# What requirements must a particular solution of a second order DE meet

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Probably a very simple question but when i'm solving simple DE's I am not sure whether to use $te^t$ or simply $e^t$ for a particular solution which involves that kind of solution of course. For example the following DE $$y'' + y'=\cos(x)$$ where you can not simply use $$y_{p1} = a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$$ but you have to use $$y_{p1} = a x \cos(x) + b x \sin(x)$$ instead. Can anyone try to explain me how you determine the right particular solution to a DE?

Comment: This is wrong. Your example would be correct if the DE were $y''+y=\cos x$. And for symmetry reasons it would only be $y_p=bx\sin x$.

Comment: Ah yes thanks... Did not copy it correctly

Comment: Here on uni we use it as a general solution to solve similar DE's  , wherein this example a = 0 since there is no cos(x) present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should just be a comment but is too long to be one: For our particular case, notice that we can rewrite the d.e. as the first-order equation $$u' - u = \cos x ,$$ where $u = y'$, but this equation is linear, so we can apply the standard method of multiply by the integrating factor $e^{-x}$, giving
$$(e^{-x} u)' = e^{-x} (u' - u) = e^{-x} \cos x,$$
so to find $y$ we need only integrate $e^{-x} \cos x$ to find $e^{-x} u$, solve for $u$, and integrate again to recover $y$. In this case the general solution turns out to be $$y(x) = -\frac{1}{2} (\sin x + \cos x) + A e^x + B ,$$ and no terms of the form $x \sin x$ or $x \cos x$ are necessary.

On the other hand, one solution to a similar differential equation $y'' + y = \cos x$ is $\frac{1}{2} x \sin x$. Notice that every function of the form $A \sin x + B \cos x$ in fact solves the corresponding homogeneous equation $y'' + y = 0$, so no particular solution of our d.e. has that form, hence we must consider a more general ansatz to find a particular solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I've changed it now but I did mean the equation you mentioned last indeed...